# role based authentication and authorization in java desktop application

Tags: java, swing, authentication

I'am develop a desktop application using java swings.
I want the authentication to be as secure as possible so please suggest the measures i should be taking to do so
also i want to implement role based authorization such that people with specific roles have access to specific modules of softwares
I've looked for various frameworks like JAAS,Springs, apache shiro but i'am not able to  map the idea to a desktop application since most of the tutorials and source available are for web application.

Comment: Why? It's trivial to bypass it for a desktop application.

Comment: which one are you taking about?

Comment: Both. Anything you try can be trivially bypassed. That's why you don't see tutorials except for web applications.

Comment: I tried implementing apache shiro, but i cannot understand how to create the shiro.ini file or set up the jdbc realm for the same.
I'am using netbeans

Comment: So You mean to say the using such frameworks for desktop application is not that important?

Comment: So You mean to say the using such frameworks for desktop application is not that important?

Comment: Do you intend to have a server that is responsible for executing all the business logic and contain all the data, with the desktop application being only a thin client?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: In that case you won't implement it on the desktop side, but the server side just like with web applications. It all depends how you intend to communicate with the server.